# How can I make the promises to stop after getting x results in Firestore

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this code that is checking if my userContacts ids exist in another collection, and I'm returning all the matches.

```
async function fetchCommonNumbers() {
    var commonNumbers = [];

    let contactsReference = admin.firestore().collection("user_contacts").doc("iNaYVsDCg3PWsDu67h75xZ9v2vh1").collection("contacts");
    const dbContactReference = admin.firestore().collection('db_contacts_meta');

    userContacts = await contactsReference.get();
    userContacts = userContacts.docs;

    await Promise.all(
        userContacts.map(userContact => {
            const DocumentID = userContact.ref.id;
                //Check if Document exists
                return dbContactReference.doc(DocumentID).get().then(dbContact => {
                    if (dbContact.exists) {
                        console.log(DocumentID);
                        commonNumbers.push(dbContact.data());
                    }
                });
        }));

    return Promise.resolve(commonNumbers);

}
```

I need to only return X matches and not all since later I'll be having million of records and I want to reduce processing time.

How can I make the Promise.all to stop when commonNumbers has X items in it?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is not implementation of cancelable promises (more info can be found here [enter link description here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-cancelable-promises)),

If you want, you can define your own "cancelable promise" wrapping a normal promise.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Do you recommend https://www.npmjs.com/package/cancelable-promise ?

Comment: yeah it's a good package.

Please mark the question as asnwered.

Comment: It did not work :( As I cant cancel the promise from within the promise

Answer (score 0):

## Reduce the processing time without "stopping" promises

You can't really make the promises *stop*. But since you're looking to **reduce the number of database calls**, what you can do is to ***selectively* resolve your promises**.

For example you can include a conditional statement in your `map` function. Like this

- `if commonNumbers.length < maxLength` then return me a Promise containing the database call
- Else, just resolve a random value (like `false` in my example)

Your promises will still be there, but you will have **limited the number of DB calls to the necessary**. It will look something like this

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const buffer = [];
const maxLenBuffer = 3;

const p = Promise.all(
  arr.map(n => {
      if (buffer.length < maxLenBuffer) {
          buffer.push(n);
          return Promise.resolve(n);
      } else {
          // There's still a promise to be resolved, but it's not a HTTP call
          // This gives you the gain of performance you're looking for
          return Promise.resolve(false);
      }
  })
);

p.then(() => console.log(buffer));
```

## Note

While this **can** reduce your database calls, the actual number of calls can be a little higher than your *maximum* specified. This is due to the asynchronous nature of the calls

Comment: I'm afraid it did not work. I think because the Promise.resolve is instant and returns a pending promise, which is not enough time for the if (buffer.length < maxLenBuffer). I'll have to await every promise, which would increase processing time.

Comment: That's true, thanks for the comment. I added an edit to include your note

Comment: Thanks for your edit. Plus in my example, I'm checking if the document exists before adding it the the array (in your case buffer). So I need the promise to finish before I know if it should be added or not

Answer (score 0):

Instead of breaking the promise in between, I would suggest you use the [limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) method do firestore.

You can query only for X number of records and this X can be either hardcoded or can come from user. Something like:

```
documentRef.orderBy("name").limit(3).get()
```

Comment: The user_contacts collection only has about 500 documents, which is not causing any problem, execution time is milliseconds. It's the db_contacts_meta collection that will later have millions of documents. I'm only executing a document check on db_contacts_meta with a know path, so I can't use limit. But my problem is that I want to stop checking for document existence after X finds.